# What happens to a clustered index when PK is created on two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I just created a table with TWO primary keys in SQL Server. One column is age, another is ID number and I set the option to CLUSTER INDEX, so it automatically creates a cluster index on both columns. However, when I query the table, the results only seem to sort the ID and completely disregard/ignore the AGE (other PK and other Cluster index column). Why is this? Why is it only sorting based on the first cluster index column?

Comment: I believe you mean you created one primary key with two columns.  Is the AGE column a varchar (or similar) or is it INT (or similar)?  If it is varchar (or similar) then the sorting won't be the same as if it is INT (or similar).

Comment: (1) You can't have created "two primary keys." (2) SQL Server is free to order results in any way that is most efficient - this won't always be in the order of the clustered index. If you want to be able to rely on a particular order, ADD AN `ORDER BY` CLAUSE. See #3 here: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions/

Comment: A bit off topic but why are you storing AGE? This is a calculated value. The instant you store it the value is stale.

Comment: I think you both got off track: the point is that, a clustered index was created using a composite primary key (two columns that make up the primary key). The first column (part 1 of the pk) is sorted while the second column is being ignored. Both columns are INTs, but then again I don't think it will make ANY difference.

Answer (score 2):

The query optimizer may decide to use the physical ordering of the rows in the table if there is no advantage in ordering any other way. So, when you select from the table using a simple query, it may be ordered this way. It is very easy to assume that the rows are physically stored in the order specified within the definition of your clustered index. But this turns out to be a false assumption.

Please view the following article for more details: [Clustered Index do “NOT” guarantee Physically Ordering or Sorting of Rows](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2013/06/02/clustered-index-do-not-guarantee-physically-ordering-or-sorting-of-rows/)

Comment: Let me start by saying that it is a very bad practice to rely on a specific order of rows to be returned by a query without specifying an `ORDER BY` clause. So, I am fairly sure there is no value in guessing why the SQL query optimizer decided to order rows in any particular fashion. That being said, if you really want to know why a query behaved a certain way at a given time, you can view the actual execution plan.

Comment: Okay, so you were correct in your answer: the rows were not physically stored. Thanks again! However, the bad/good practice was beside the point, the point was why these items do not show up as sorted when they are either physically/logically saved sorted. But you were correct, it was not physical save, just logical. And I was wrong because I trusted what I saw on the screen and I should have been looking at the exec plan.